# Call C# method from another class using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, inheritance, methods

I have a jQuery-method that returns the text of a `div` when clicked on. This method is in a `.js` file. I want to use a method from another class that uses the text from the div that was clicked on as parameter.

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#clicked div', function () {
    var temp = $(this).html();
    temp = temp.replace('<span>', '').replace('</span>', '');

    // someMethod(temp);
});
```

`Class.cs`:

```
public string someMethod(string str){
    return str;
}
```

How do I access this method from the JavaScript file?

Comment: .cs says to me C#.  If this is the case, its not going to run in a browser!

Comment: As @JustinHarvey said .cs = Codebehind, the only that you can get the text is making Ajax call.

Comment: You can't call C# code from JavaScript code.  They're running on two completely different machines, in two completely different technology stacks.  What you *can* do is make an AJAX call from JavaScript to a server-side resource (page?  action method?  handler?) and that server-side resource can invoke the C# method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try the AJAX call.

Comment: You should look at MVC or WebAPI.

Comment: check out this link: http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Make that class static and add that method ie someMethod
there, and then make an ajax call to that method

```
public static class Yourclass
{
  public static string someMethod(string str)
  {
    return str;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no mention of MVC or any other framework that would allow him to access this. As well as the fact that making a method static would make absolutely no difference.

Comment: It works. Just add the tag `[WebMethod]` on top of your static method and you may call it from javascript. The question states it is about C#, javascript and JQuery.

Comment: @RicardoAppleton C# could be anything. A .dll library, console app etc. As you don't know how the method is contained, how can you say with 100% certainty that using the [WebMethod] decorator would work?? The point I was also making was that making it static would have no effect.

Comment: You're right. I assumed that his Class.cs would be a webpage's cs code.